# Common (automatically included) headers in Androin NDK build?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, precompiled-headers, android-ndk

I want to set up common header files to be included automatically into every include/source file in the project. I have to build with ndk a large cocos2d-x project which compiles in Xcode and has some commonly used headers in prefix.pch. Is it possible to configure such headers in Android NDK builds?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to use this http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25412#makechanges but have been having some trouble so far. I applied that patch, and it seems to be including my PCH file, but toward the end of compilation I get this message:

```
make: *** No rule to make target '/cygdrive/redacted/prefix.pch', needed by 'obj/local/redacted/prefix.pch.gch'. Stop.
```

Could be because I'm using Cygwin, I have no idea..